# printing from datagridview it gives me error message

Tags: vb.net

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbeUF.jpg)please some one help me with this issue. some one gave me this code and when i try it didn't work for me. the problem is when i change Y with rowIndex the printed values will be on top of one another and if i swap rowIndex with Y the error message comes. i dont understand what i didnt include, its because im new for this vb thing.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRivm.jpg)

'first option

```vb
Dim y0 = 10

Dim rowHeight = 50
For rowIndex = 0 To rowCount - 1
    Dim y = y0 + rowIndex * rowHeight

    e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView6.Rows(y).Cells(1).Value, ReportBodyFont, Brushes.Black, 50, 320)
    e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView6.Rows(y).Cells(3).Value, ReportBodyFont, Brushes.Blue, 400, 320)

Next
```

'second option

```vb
Dim rowCount As Integer = DataGridView6.Rows.Count
For i = 0 To rowCount - 1

    e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView6.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value, ReportBodyFont, Brushes.Black, 50, 320)
    e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView6.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value, ReportBodyFont, Brushes.Blue, 400, 320)

Next
```

I try the 2nd also but its the same the printed value from datagridview are on top of one another. please some one help me with this issue, i want to print only the value not with tables. see the attached screenshot picture for your ref.

'3rd option

```vb
Dim rowCount As Integer = DataGridView6.Rows.Count

For i = 0 To rowCount - 1
Dim y0 = 330
    Dim rowHeight = 40

    For rowIndex = 0 To rowCount - 1
        Dim y = y0 + rowIndex * rowHeight

        'Print at y.
        e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView6.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value, ReportBodyFont, Brushes.Black, 50, y)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView6.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value, ReportBodyFont, Brushes.Blue, 400, y)
             
    Next

Next
```

Comment: Your DrawStrings are always printing in the same location.

Comment: `Dim y = y0 + rowIndex * rowHeight`  y is not your row number here, which is why you are getting an error.

Comment: so what is the row then?

Comment: You have it right in your second option, because "i" represents the row number.  But everything is printing at the same spot: `50, 320`.  That's where your "y" variable from the first option would come in.

Comment: yes "i" is the row and i understand ur point but that is not the solution, even if i change the vertical and horizontal alignment its the same it hold the same point the second row of the datagridview meaning its the same on top of one another. its my 2nd day on this problem.

Comment: Click on the "edit" link under your post and show us the fixed code.  Like I said, you are always printing in the same locations `50, 320` and `400, 320`.  That 320 needs to be a variable that increments to a new row height.

Comment: i think im following u now, with what should i change the variable? what is the coding? please help

Comment: `...ReportBodyFont, Brushes.Black, 50, y)`

Comment: boss it helps but still its on top of one another. i wish i can show you the print out. i think ur closer to solution. i put the current coding on the edited main question. and also the screen shot.

Comment: Why do you have two for-loops?  You only need one.

Comment: ur right it works now!!! thanks a lot !!! u save my day.

Answer (score 2):

thank you – LarsTech.
this is the correct code for printing.

```
 Dim rowCount As Integer = DataGridView6.Rows.Count
    Dim y0 = 370
    Dim rowHeight = 20
    For rowIndex = 0 To rowCount - 1
        Dim y = y0 + rowIndex * rowHeight
        e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView6.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(1).Value, ReportBodyFont, Brushes.Black, 70, y)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView6.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(3).Value, ReportBodyFont, Brushes.Blue, 405, y)
    Next
```